# Why can we access the variable itself while initializing it?

Tags: ios, swift3

From a raywenderlich article, I saw this code snippet:

```
 // new way, Swift 3
 if let ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() {

  let rectangle = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 512, height: 512)
    ctx.setFillColor(UIColor.blue().cgColor)
    ctx.setStrokeColor(UIColor.white().cgColor)
    ctx.setLineWidth(10)
    ctx.addRect(rectangle)
    ctx.drawPath(using: .fillStroke)

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
}
```

Why can we access the variable(ctx) itself while initializing it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The `ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()` statement has got a reference to the UI context object and if that fails (as it's optional) you won't enter the `if` clause.  If it succeeds, the reference is ready for use and its properties can be set.

Answer (score 0):

Ah! The wonders of Swift optionals! This is actually a Swift safe-unwrap pattern. See how UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() returns a `CGContext?`? The `?` means it may return a nil, it's an optional. This `if let` structure let's you safely unwrap UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() into a variable and safely use it inside the `if` scope.

[image: CGContext is optional]

You can read more about this [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html).

I hope this helps!